How to restore SELinux context for home directory?
I installed fresh new Fedora 41 Xfce with /home/kuba directory in different partition from Fedora updated since version 35. The upgrade failed (maybe because I deleted pulsesecure without uninstalling it, to make some space for the new packages).
How I have errors from SELinux:
type=AVC msg=audit(1730469601.380:2566): avc:  denied  { write } for 
pid=3495014 comm="pool-tumblerd" name="normal" dev="sda5"
ino=91488302 scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:thumb_t:s0-
s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0

The localized message looked like this (not sure how to get original locale in GUI):
SELinux powstrzymuje /usr/lib64/tumbler-1/tumblerd przed dostępem write w katalog normal.

I want to restore the home directory into proper state, how can I do this. I've tried:

sudo semanage fcontext -a -t home_root_t "/home/kuba(/.*)?"

sudo semanage fcontext -a -t user_home_t "/home/kuba(/.*)?"

## this one gives an error
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t thumb_t "/home/kuba(/.*)?"

sudo restorecon -Rv /home/kuba


But still, I don't have thumbnails on image files downloaded from Google Drive or send via Bluetooth.
How can I restore and add proper SELinux context to my home directory, so I don't get SELinux errors?

Have you tried sudo restorecon -Rv /home

@ArtemS.Tashkinov it doesn't work, I obviously need some SELinux context that I'm missing.

I've created a new user and inspected the SELinux context:
$ sudo adduser foo
$ ls -lD /home
drwx------.   3 foo  foo  unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0  4096 11-02 14:46 foo
drwxr-xr-x. 127 kuba kuba unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0     12288 11-01 20:00 kuba

So in order to restore the proper context, I needed to run those commands
$ sudo semanage fcontext -m -t user_home_dir_t "/home/kuba(/.*)?"
$ sudo restorecon -Rv /home/kuba

And wait for a while. This seems to solve the problem
